# React Hooks infinite loop Memory leak?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, infinite-loop, use-effect

Hello i have a problem with infinite loops. All the exampels i look at makes the loop go away. But then it wont  update my view if i dont refresh. I want the items to appear when something gets added. i thought my example would work but it does not. I dont know how to fix it

```
      const [ReadBookingTimes, SetBookingTimes] = useState([]);
      const [readStatus, setStatus] = useState("");
        
        const getBookingTimes = async () => {
            try {
              const response = await Axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}`);
              console.log(response);
              // debugger;
              SetBookingTimes(response.data);
              // setStatus("Connection sucsessfull");
            } catch (err) {
              setStatus("Error getting BookingTimes");
            }
          };
        
          //reupdate State and prevent infinite loop
          useEffect(() => {
            getBookingTimes(ReadBookingTimes);
          }, [ReadBookingTimes]); //);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` has a dependancy `ReadBookingTimes` which updates every time. Bascially, you update the `ReadBookingTimes` every single time over and over again.

What you should do is to add a condition to check if your data is already loaded and if so, don't call the function:

```
const [ReadBookingTimes, SetBookingTimes] = useState([]);
const [readStatus, setStatus] = useState("");

const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);


 const getBookingTimes = async () => {
     // Your fetch code
     setDataLoaded(true)
 }

 useEffect(() => {
     // don't go any further of data is already loaded.
     if (dataLoaded) return;

     getBookingTimes(ReadBookingTimes);
 }, [ReadBookingTimes, dataLoaded]);
```

Now you won't get stuck in a loop. And anytime you want to reload the data, you can change the `dataLoaded` to `false` and `useEffect` will call the `getBookingTimes` function again.

In case you want to get the data every 2 minutes for example, you can add a timeout to change the `dataLoaded` state every time causing another data reload.

Comment: should my dataloaded be after the response data?

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt update my view when adding items. but it doesnt loop anymore or maybe it doesnt trigger now because im loading data with Postman? or it should rerender?

Comment: Yes, after loading your response. What do you mean by adding items? You're not adding any new item.

Comment: Right now im using postman to add data to the list. but i will create a function to add stuf to the list. i want it to auto render so i can see the items without refreshing the page.

Comment: You can set the `dataLoaded` back to `false` when you add a new item and then your `usEffect` function will be triggered and then it loads the data again causing a re-render.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info! appreciate it. by the way . now i see that objects gets loaded twice when i console.log is this intended?

Comment: Put `setDataLoaded(true)` befor  `SetBookingTimes(response.data)` and it should fix the problem.